# How can I block abusing Spigot PlugIns (Server run in Dockers)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I want to create Dockers on Ubuntu.
The problem is that user can run plugins with code like these:

```
public static void create() throws IOException {
    String path = "/";
    String fname="test.cpp";
    File fl=new File(path+fname);
    fl.createNewFile();
}
```

This will create a file "test.cpp" in the "/" direction of the root-server.
How can I block abuses with spigot, forgeserver etc. like this?

Comment: You probably can't. If the Minecraft process has file-write permissions to a directory, then the mod has file-write permissions to the same directory. That said, no Minecraft mod will ever have a reason to create *C++ source files in the root directory.* And if they do, *stop using that mod.*